# Why is my answer a 'bad answer' and being downvoted?

Tags: discussion, support

I supplied an answer in this question :-

[Laptop charge 126W for a 120W laptop](https://superuser.com/questions/1322569/laptop-charge-126w-for-a-120w-laptop)

and it is being downvoted without comment. Why?

The answer is factually correct, and consistent with what manufacturers will give as guidance. Furthermore, The other answer us being upvoted, but contains advise that could damage the equipment, or lead to injury of the user...

Comment: I'll have a look at that question. Thanks

Comment: I suppose all I can hope for is other users see the validity of my answer, and upvote instead.

Comment: Or edit your answer to elaborate on your suggestion. For example you don't state any sources or describe why you think a small change in output voltage of the charger could affect the device.

Comment: The other answer on the question has 6 upvotes and is equally source-bereft. I'd feel decidedly irked about the seeming double standards, if nothing else.

Comment: fair enough. i'll retract my ire for the greater good.